# Is $f(x)=+\infty $ for every $x \in \Bbb {R} ^* =\Bbb{R} \cup \{ +\infty , - \infty \} $ constant function?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Is $f(x)=+\infty $ for every $x \in \Bbb {R} ^* =\Bbb{R} \cup \{  +\infty , - \infty \} $ constant function ?

Note that $f :  \Bbb{R} ^* \to \Bbb{R} ^* $

Here is definition of constant function in wikipedia  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_function

Is $f$ well define ?

If this function is constant can we draw in plane ? We know that The graph of the constant function y=c is a horizontal line in the plane ( in $ \Bbb{R} $).

Comment: Using Wikipedia's definition of "constant function", isn't this...well...obvious?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is a constant function. No, you cannot draw it in the plane $\Bbb R^2$, because the plane does not contain points having infinite coordinates. You would have to consider a different "plane", namely $(\Bbb R^*) ^2$, but then it is not clear how to *graphically* represent this as a "plane".

Comment: Maybe with a sphere? It's $S^2$

Comment: @Ant: The sphere usually means that we attach a single infinity, i.e. we consider $- \infty = \infty$ (for clarity, the projective line has a single point at infinity). Therefore, I don't see how to do it with spheres.

Comment: Fair point! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since $f$ takes on the same value $c = + \infty$ at every value of $x$, we say that $f$ is constant (on the entire domain $\mathbb R*$).

You can plot it, sure! Just get an inifinitely-sized paper, put origo in the center, and draw a straight line *at the top*.

In other words, no, we cannot plot it. Hopefully the above sentence makes it clear why. :)